# tracker auto run on reactive subscription

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

i"m trying to recompute autorun  on collection update  ,
i only manage to get it to work when adding autopublish.the code below works perfectly  .

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
   var pages = Posts.find().fetch();
    _.each(pages, function(page) {
      console.log("react");
        if (typeof page.adress !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof page.lat !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof page.long !== 'undefined') {

            var objMarker = {
                id: page._id,
                lat: page.lat,
                lng: page.long,
                title: page.name
            };

            // check if marker already exists
            if (!gmaps.markerExists('id', objMarker.id))
                gmaps.addMarker(objMarker);

        }
    });
});
```

}

what i need is reacting on subscription.
i have this publication defined :

```
Meteor.publish('allposts', function() {
```

return Posts.find({});
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code looks like subscribing to the records on the client is missing

try this

```
remove autopublish package
```

on server publish records

```
  Meteor.publish('allposts', function() {
    return Posts.find({}); 
});
```

In the client, subscribe to the records in a reactive computation

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
      Meteor.subscribe('allposts');
})
```

Now In the client you can use `Posts.find({})` wherever you want it will be reactive